# T-SQL create table with primary keys

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Hello I wan to create a new table based on another one and create primary keys as well.

Currently this is how I'm doing it. Table B has no primary keys defined. But I would like to create them in table A. Is there a way using this select top 0 statement to do that? Or do I need to do an ALTER TABLE after I created tableA?

Thanks

```
select TOP 0 *
INTO [tableA]
FROM [tableB]
```

Comment: Note: you can always have only a **single** primary key on any given table - you cannot have multiple primary keys....

Comment: Rather than alter just skip the into and create table.

Comment: The problem is that doing a create table I need to specify all my columns...the select INTO was an quick way to create those table if I don't care about the columns. I guess I need to do an ALTER after creating the table. Thanks for you feedback

Comment: If you're just trying to create an empty table, why not right-click the table in Object Explorer > Script table as > Create To > New Query Editor Window? With the right options set in Tools > Options > SQL Server Object Explorer > Scripting, you can have it create indexes / constraints etc. Then all you have to do is find/replace the old name with the new name. (And add the primary key constraint that doesn't already exist in Table B - nothing will do that for you automatically.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is NO. SELECT INTO will always create a HEAP table and, according to [Books Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> Indexes, constraints, and triggers defined in the source table are not
>   transferred to the new table, nor can they be specified in the
>   SELECT...INTO statement. If these objects are required, you must
>   create them after executing the SELECT...INTO statement.

So, after executing SELECT INTO you need to execute an ALTER TABLE or CREATE UNIQUE INDEX in order to add a primary key.

Also, if dbo.TableB does not already have an IDENTITY column (or if it does and you want to leave it out for some reason), and you need to create an artificial primary key column (rather than use an existing column in dbo.TableB to serve as the new primary key), you could use the IDENTITY function to create a candidate key column. But you still have to add the constraint to TableA after the fact to make it a primary key, since just the IDENTITY function/property alone does not make it so.

```
-- This statement will create a HEAP table
SELECT Col1, Col2, IDENTITY(INT,1,1) Col3
INTO dbo.MyTable
FROM dbo.AnotherTable;

-- This statement will create a clustered PK
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable_Col3 PRIMARY KEY (Col3);
```

Comment: Of course this will error out if dbo.MyTable has an IDENTITY column already.

Comment: It will raise an error if another SELECT column has IDENTITY (ex. Col1 or Col2).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Table has an IDENTITY is not he same as SELECT column has IDENTITY.  And if table B has no PK then a pretty good chance it does not have an IDENTITY.

Comment: @Blam thanks, but in the question they say `SELECT *`. Therefore, if the table has an IDENTITY column, then so does the SELECT. Adding an IDENTITY column in its place instead of selecting the one that already exists doesn't magically make that column a PK, only an IDENTITY column. So I was merely pointing out that I don't understand the relevance of including that in the code sample at all. The way that code sample is introduced makes it sound like that column will have some kind of constraint on it, when it won't. An IDENTITY is not a PK or UNIQUE by itself. You have to add it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand So what about the question.  You responded to the comment of column.  "Pretty good chance" indicates I am aware an IDENTITY is not automatically a PK. But there is a pretty good chance a an IDENTITY is declared as the PK.

Comment: @Blam my comment here was ABOUT THE ANSWER. And my reply to you was still about that. What is the point of `IDENTITY(INT,1,1)`? If the source table already has an `IDENTITY` column, and the question says `SELECT *`, what does it add? If the source table does not have an `IDENTITY` column, what does it add? The wording before the code sample suggests that this could make a primary key, when it can't. *NO SYNTAX FOR SELECT INTO CAN DO THIS.*

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Yes, I get your point but there is no information within this question regarding the existence of an IDENTITY column in the source table. The reason of adding that IDENTITY column was to create a PK because an IDENTITY column hash unique values and, also, doesn't allow NULLs. And if somebody is curios and he/she reads the first line of my answer the he/she will hind this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: @AaronBertrand: The title of this question is about [How to]"[...] create table with primary keys" (and from the content of this question) using "SELECT INTO". And my answer is clear enough, I hope: "The short answer is NO. SELECT INTO will always create a HEAP table and, ... `Indexes, constraints ... defined in the source table are not transferred`". `IDENTITY` columns are not indexes/constraints/triggers.

Comment: Added clarity, maybe you'll get my drift now.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The commented you deleted sure appeared to be a response to the comment above your comment to me.  I tested the syntax in this answer on a table B both with and would an identity and it worked for me as long as the identity was not Col1 or Col2.

Comment: @Blam go away. Bogdan and I have resolved the problem I had with his answer.

Answer (score 5):

`SELECT INTO` does not support copying any of the indexes, constraints, triggers or even computed columns and other table properties, aside from the `IDENTITY` property (as long as you don't apply an expression to the `IDENTITY` column.

So, you will have to add the constraints after the table has been created and populated.

Comment: Thanks, ill Do an ALTER after the select INTO